# Serialize form to and from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

I want to serialize a form into json, process the json object, then reserialize it to send to a php script via ajax.

Here is a rough example of what I want to do:

```
s = $('.dia_req_form').serialize();
j = //convert s to json ...HOW??
if(j.name)
{
    alert("you must enter a name");
}
if(selectedID)
{
    j.id = selectedID;
}
s = //serialize j ...HOW??
```

You can see the 2 parts that say HOW??

Comment: Why not do the checks *before* you serialize? :)

Comment: @Nick I could validate before hand, but I still need to add other variables to the list. But I could always append `&foo=bar` to the serialized string. If thats the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) like this:

```
//validate here
var obj = $('.dia_req_form').serializeArray();
if(selectedID) {
  obj.push({ name: 'id', value: selectedID });
}
var s = $.param(obj); //s can be used for submission
```

Internally, [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is really equivalent to `$.param($(this).serializeArray())`, so all this is doing is breaking the steps apart, adding an item if needed.

[`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) is an array of objects with 2 properties (`name` and `value`), all we're doing is adding some object to the array if needed, *then* calling [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to make it a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib, `$.serializeObject` is a variant of existing `$.serialize` method which, instead of encoding form elements to string, converts form elements to a valid JSON object which can be used in your JavaScript application.

https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject